# Is it possible to have drag and drop from a ListView to a TreeView in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, treeview

If it's not possible, I can also use 2 TreeView controls. I just won't have a hierarchy in the second TreeView control. It's gonna act like some sort of repository.

Any code sample or tutorial would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ListView` does not support drag-and-drop naturally, but you can enable it with a small bit of code:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822483

Here's an example that specifically does drag-and-drop from a `ListView` to a `TreeView` (it's an Experts Exchange link, so just wait a few seconds and then scroll to the bottom, where you'll find the answers):

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_CSharp/Q_22675010.html

**Update:**  Code from the link:

- Create a listview and a treeview. ( In my example, the listview is called listView1 and the treeview is called tvMain )
- On the treeview, set AllowDrop to true.
- Create an ItemDrag event on the listview

---

```
private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.DoDragDrop(listView1.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
```

In this example items from the listview are copied to the 'drop' object.
Now, create a DragEnter event on the treeview:

```
private void tvMain_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
```

This was easy. Now the hard part starts. The following code adds the selected (and dragged) listview items to an existing node (make sure you have at least one node already in your treeview or the example will fail!)

Create a DragDrop event on the treeview:

```
private void tvMain_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode n;

            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection", false))
            {
                Point pt = ((TreeView)sender).PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                TreeNode dn = ((TreeView)sender).GetNodeAt(pt);
                ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection lvi = (ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection");

                foreach (ListViewItem item in lvi)
                {
                    n = new TreeNode(item.Text);
                    n.Tag = item;

                    dn.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)n.Clone());
                    dn.Expand();
                    n.Remove();
                }
            }
        }
```

To change the cursor while dragging, you have to create a GiveFeedback event for the ListView control:

```
private void listView1_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
        {
            e.UseDefaultCursors = false;

            if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Copy)
            {
                Cursor.Current = new Cursor(@"myfile.ico");
            }
        }
```

`myfile.ico` should be in the same directory as the .exe file.

This is just a simple example. You can extend it any way you like.

Comment: Thanks, but what about dragging from 1 control into another?

Comment: Although it doesn't let me to see anything, just a blurry screen with please subscribe overlayed on top.

Comment: Rats! - it let me scroll down when I first visited it a couple of minutes ago, but now it isn't showing the answers.

Comment: @Joan: I think they don't show the answers at the bottom maybe 95% of the time, so you just have to refresh until the answer shows up. They want to make money, which is understandable.

Comment: Thanks man for posting the code, yeah they are bastards :O SO is better and it's free.

Comment: they set a cookie sometimes then they won't show the answers again to you until you either delete it or open the page from the Google Cache (depending on the browser you are using, Google cache is easier)

Comment: private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.DoDragDrop(listView1.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Copy);                                              
        }

here listView1.DoDragDrop(listView1.SelectedItems,DragDropEffects.Copy);
shows it has some invalid arguments.