# Dragging items from one list view to a second list view

Tags: c#, winforms

I came across this post in MSDN forums and they are saying this is not supported at all. Really?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/08a012a6-74bf-4ac4-b984-adda3687e6f1

Are you aware of any samples that actually have done that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the post in your link is referring to WinForms. It's doable in WinForms; it just may not be very straightforward - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045427/is-it-possible-to-have-drag-and-drop-from-a-listview-to-a-treeview-in-winforms)

Comment: Your post seems to be about Metro/HTML5

Comment: yep, correct...good link too, thanks. It is doing it from a ListView to a TreeView...Do you know anything that moves between two listviews?

Comment: Not specifically, but I don't imagine a ListView would be much more difficult